# List as element of list of lists or multidimensional lists as a grid

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to create a lat/lon grid that contains an array of found indices where two conditions are met for a lat/lon combination. This approach might be too complicated, but using a meshgrid or numpy broadcasting failed also. If there is a better approach, feel free to share your knowlegde. :-)

*Round lat/lon values to gridsize resolution of 1° but retain full length of array:*

```
x = np.around(lon, decimals=0) 
y = np.around(lat, decimals=0)
```

arrays consists of longitude/latitude values from -180 to 180 and -82° to 82°; multiple douplets possible

*Check for each combination of lat/lon how many measurements are available for 1°/1° grid point:*

```
a = arange(-180,181)    
b = arange(-82,83)
totalgrid = [ [ 0 for i in range(len(b)) ] for j in range(len(a)) ]
for d1 in range(len(a)):
    for d2 in range(len(b)):
        totalgrid[d1][d2]=np.where((x==a[d1])&(y==b[d2]))[0]
```

This method fails and returns only a list of lists with empty arrays. I can't figure out why it's not working properly. 
Replacing the last line by:

```
totalgrid[d1][d2]=np.where((x==a[0])&(y==b[0]))[0]
```

returns all found indices from lon/lat that are present at -180°/-82°. Unfortunately it takes a while. Am I missing a for loop somewhere?!

**The Problem in more detail:**
@askewchan
Unfortunately this one does not solve my original problem.
As expected the result represents the groundtrack quite well.
[image: Groundtrack as result of histogram]
But besides the fact that I need the total number of points for each grid point, I also need each single index of lat/lon combinations in the lat/lon array for further computations.
Let's assume I have an array

```
lat(100000L,), lon(100000L,) and a third one array(100000L,)
```

which corresponds to the measurement at each point. I need every index of all 1°/1° combinations in lat/lon, to check this index in the array(100000L,) if a condition is met. Now lets assume that the indices[10000,10001,10002,..,10025] of lat/lon are on the same gridpoint. For those indices I need to check whether array[10000,10001,10002,..,10025] now met a condition, i.e. np.where(array==0). With cts.nonzero() I only get the index in the histogram. But then all information of each point contributing to the value of the histogram is lost. Hopefully you get what was my initial problem.

Comment: So it seems that you need a list of lists `a` where `a[i]` is a list of all indices to `lat` and `lon` that fall into the `i`th 1° bin?

Comment: Don't know why my previous post works now. But it returns at each lon/lat (d1/d2) point a list of indices where the condition was met. But unfortunately it takes several minutes. Which is obvious, because it iterates 59040 times through lat/lon. Is there a faster way to get the same results? I like your histogram approach @askewchan, but unfortunately all the information I'm interested in is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the goal here, but you want to count how many lat/lon pairs you have in each 1° section?  This is what a histogram does:

```py
lon = np.random.random(5000)*2*180 - 180
lat = np.random.random(5000)*2*82 - 82

a = np.arange(-180,181)
b = np.arange(-82,83)

np.histogram2d(lon, lat, (a,b))
#(array([[ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  2.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  1.,  0.],
#        ..., 
#        [ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
```

The indices where you have a nonzero count would be at:

```py
cts.nonzero()
#(array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 359, 359, 359]),
# array([  2,  23,  25, ..., 126, 140, 155]))
```

You can plot it too:

```py
cts, xs, ys = np.histogram2d(lon, lat, (a,b))

pyplot.imshow(cts, extent=(-82,82,-180,180))
```

[image: latlonghist]

Comment: Ok, with your histogram I get at least the total number of each pair. Therefore the image would represent more or less the groundtrack of the satellite. But I need the indices of such pairs in lat/lon to check a third array of the length of lat/lon for some condition. Therefore I have to store the indices in an array, right? Maybe I'am thinking way too complicated and there is another approach.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed answer. Unfortunately this one does not solve my original problem. Due to the limitations for comments, I edited the initial post and added a detailed problem report.